# Python 3.5 ctypes libc printf() only prints first byte of string Windows 7/10

Tags: python, c, windows, pydev

I'm trying to follow one of the Gray Hat Python examples and it works fine in Python 2.7, but in Python 3.5 the result is truncated.

```
from ctypes import * 

msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string = "Hello World!\n"
msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s\n", message_string)
```

You can see below the the output of the code above is just the letter `T`.

[image]

Based one some other posts similar to this one, adding a `b` to the last line helps but then the `message_string` is truncated.

```
from ctypes import * 

msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string = "Hello World!\n"
msvcrt.printf(b"Testing: %s\n", message_string)
```

[image]

How do I get it to print the entire string stored in the `message_string` variable, using Python 3.5 on Windows 7 or 10?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the text into a charset the function can handle?

Comment: Set `msvcrt.printf.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,)` to enforce type checking the first argument. Additional arguments for this variadic function depend on the format string, so just leave them unchecked, but use common sense here. Python 3 uses Unicode strings, so you have to encode the string as `bytes`, as the previous comment suggests.  Also, avoid using `cdll` because it globally caches modules, which cache function pointers, which leads to prototype conflicts (i.e. `restype`, `argtypes`, and `errcheck`) between libraries and scripts. Use `msvcrt = ctypes.CDLL('msvcrt')`.

Comment: Also, take "Gray Hat Python" with a large grain of salt. I've seen numerous examples based on code from that book, enough to know that it's filled with code that cavalierly ignores setting prototypes, such that a lot of the code that depends on pointers and module handles breaks in 64-bit Windows, or doing proper error checking, such as using the `use_last_error` parameter of `WinDLL` to enable `ctypes.get_last_error` and `ctypes.set_last_error` (a safe `GetLastError` and `SetLastError` based on thread local storage).

Comment: I did try various methods shown on the python site `16.16. ctypes — A foreign function library for Python` like `create_string_buffer()` and `create_unicode_buffer()` and can get them working using the native Python `print()`. Perhaps it is best to stick with 2.7, although I thought for sure that I read an article stating 2.7 was no longer supported...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it to work! Needed to add the `b` in the variable declaration too. Such a small detail too...See adjusted code below:

```
from ctypes import * 

msvcrt = CDLL('msvcrt')
message_string = b"Hello World!\n"
msvcrt.printf(b"Testing: %s\n", message_string)
```

Tested on Windows 7 64bit, w/ Python 3.5, & Windows 10 64bit w/ Python 3.4

[image]

Gray Hat Python - chapter1-printf.py - example

Comment: The small detail of the `b` prefix, which is a `bytes` literal, is the difference between passing an ASCII byte string `b"Hello World!\n"` versus a UTF-16LE encoded string (on Windows) `b'H\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00!\x00\n\x00'`.

Comment: If any library you've imported also defines something like `cdll.msvcrt.printf.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_char_p, c_int)`, then your code is broken again because `printf` will require 3 arguments. The `cdll` and `windll` loaders were a bad idea. Change it to `msvcrt = CDLL('msvcrt')` to get a private reference to `msvcrt`.

Comment: Thanks for the added insight @eryksun. I was actually wondering what the differences were for both points you mentioned.